# Package e1071 fails to download

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

I wish to install the VIM package for imputing some missing data in RStudio but I am getting an error with the related e1071 package.

The VIM package installs O.K. but the related e1071 fails for the following reason:

```
> install.packages("e1071", dependencies = T)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/John/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
e1071  1.6-7  1.6-8              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/e1071_1.6-7.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/e1071_1.6-7.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/e1071_1.6-7.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘e1071’ failed
```

What do I need to do to install this package?

Comment: It looks like `e1071` was recently updated, so you might just have to restart R and try again.

Comment: @Kevin Ushey, thanks for the answer, yeah that did the trick! If you wish to post this as the answer I will accept. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got stuck in between a CRAN update of the `e1071` package. When your R session asked what version of `e1071` was current, it reported (and cached) version 1.6-7; however, soon after version 1.6-8 was uploaded to CRAN. Because of that, the R session attempted to download 1.6-7, but failed as only 1.6-8 was then available.

Restarting R should clear the local package listing cache and get you on your way.